# Business level application fails to start in websphere application server

Tags: osgi, ibm-was

My business level application in WAS is not starting and fails with an exception saying Caused by:

> org.apache.aries.application.management.spi.repository.ContextException: Unable to find bundle org.apache.aries.proxy.api/1.0.0

I uploaded org.apache.aries.proxy.api 1.0.0  in the internal bundle repository of osgi - but the error isnt getting resolved.

Could someone please help me understand this problem and also suggest some solutions?

Thanks and regards,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

well, I am not sure what the problem was - I undeployed and then redeployed the asset again and now the application started properly